# The physics of microwave vacuum tubes

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, electronics, electrical-engineering

I've searched this extensively, but I couldn't find anything (the only thing I found was [this one](http://www.tubebooks.org/Books/Spangenberg_vacuum_tubes.pdf)). I know this question seems to be more of engineering than physics, but I've found some [engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202985/) questions in here, so, I'll give a try.

I'd like a book which explains vacuum tubes (their design: diodes, triodes, cathode-ray tubes, klystrons, magnetrons, etc). I do not want a book which teaches how to manufacture circuits with these tubes, I want to know about the tube themselves: *especially the physics of how they work*. And, most importantly, I do not want books who hide the math. Additional points for high power tubes and microwave tubes (especially high powered microwave tubes! :D). My preference goes for rigorous books.

Well, I'm comfortable with classical electrodynamics at a graduate level, so, it would be nice to have a book that actually would assume this knowledge (I am asking a lot.. I know.... its okay if the book you recommend doesn't meet all the requirements).

Comment: suggest you post this on the amateur radio stack exchange. Lots of vacuum tube experts over there.

Comment: Principles of Vacuum Tubes. _J.W. Gewartowski & H.A. Watson_, 1965 is going to be the most modern large format book dedicated on the subject.  Note that actual useful models tend to be based on phenomenological equations as real applications rarely work well with the pure physics models.  Remember that these are _nonlinear systems_ and thus there aren't going to be generalized solutions and most will be numerical.